# can kubernetes role override clusterrole?

Tags: kubernetes, rbac, k8s-cluster-role

For example I have a role that gives permission to user get list of pods from specific namespace. And I have a clusterRole that gives permission to user get list of pods from all namespaces.

can user get all pods from all namespaces? or does role override clusterRole because role is more specific?

I know this doesn't make sense.  But what if I do it by mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#role-and-clusterrole

> Permissions are purely additive (there are no "deny" rules).

That means you can't get less rights, only more if user is bound to multiple Roles or ClusterRoles

Answer (score 1):

In kubernetes **ClusterRole** takes precedence over the **Roles**. Because the **Role** is bound to a certain **namespace** whereas the ClusterRole is a **non-namespaced** resource. Whenever a user requests for resources, the kubernetes will check the roles and clusterroles assigned to that **user** or **service account**.

If there is any conflict between **Roles** and **ClusterRoles** then the ClusterRole overrides the Role **permissions** for a **user** or **service account** in kubernetes.

For more detailed information refer to the [Official RBAC Document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#role-and-clusterrole)